# From Java Object to JSON String using javax.json

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

Is it possible to create a JSON string from `List<MyClass>` using Java EE 7's `javax.json` library without iterating over the `List<MyClass>`?

This is what I do now and the performance is unacceptable with 2000 iteration. Any suggestion?

```
List<MyClass> items = MyDB.getAllItems();
JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
builder.add("success", true);
JsonArrayBuilder childrenArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

for (MyClass item : items) {
     childrenArrayBuilder.add(
        Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("id", getTreeNodeId(item) + "-" + (idSplit[1]))
            .add("nodeStatus", b)
            .add("text", item.getName())
            .add("leaf", false));
}
```

Comment: Easy speaking If you want all data you must iterate over all - if you want simply 100 entries you can iterator to 100.

Comment: No matter how you do it, somebody _has to iterate over the List_. How else should all items be part of your JSON?

Comment: The list contains around 5000 items and the performance isn't good if I want to iterate on that.

Comment: what do you mean alex? using gson or JSONArray it is possible!

Comment: This is a bit old, but still worth responding....  @sina: If you're using gson, then in its internals, gson is iterating over all 5000 items.  Performance may be better or worse, but either way it's going to be an O(n) operation.  The difference is going to be mainly in how much code you write, not in whether the VM is iterating over the whole list.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a lot of objects in your loops which is probably not necessary. With GSON and as far as `MyClass` contains only what you need I will do something like:

```
List<MyClass> list = MyDB.getAllItems();
GSON gson = new GSON();
String myString = gson.toJson(list);
```